# Extended Metadata Entities in Microsoft Academic

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

A query using the extended metadata entities does not work. Do i need to pass these parameters using a different URL Parameter other than "attributes"

```
For example, the following query does not work (returns 400)
GET https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(J.JN=='computer')&model=latest&count=10&offset=0&attributes=Id,Ti,Y,D,CC,AuN,AA.AfN,J.JN,W,E,D,E,S.U HTTP/1.1
Host: api.projectoxford.ai
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
```

Simply removing "S.U" from the list of entities makes it work

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your interest in Microsoft Academic!

Attribute “E” is a JSON string which consists of extended metadata attributes.
You can get only full contents of E, i.e. all extended metadata attributes.
You can use only entity attributes in “attributes” parameter of URI, not extended metadata attributes.

https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/academic-knowledge-api/documentation/entityattributes>

So, if you need to get S.U you should get the value of attribute "E" and parse corresponding JSON.

Example (here I use only three attributes: Id,Ti, E in order to make output shorter):

```
https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(J.JN=='computer')&model=latest&count=10&offset=0&attributes=Id,Ti,E
```

Please, let us know if you have any questions or suggestions.

We would love to hear what you think about Cognitive Services:
http://cognitive.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thank you, i noticed that the E field is actually a JSON string after posting the question